# Laravel date validation if checkbox is selected

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I'm trying to build an application in `Laravel` where I need to take input user's job experience with their start date and end date. There is a  use case where the user can be currently working in any organization, so there will not be any `end_date`. I need to skip `end_date` in case there is no input or check `currently_working` checkbox (trying Boolean value) validate the user inputs, my validation rule look something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'employeee_type'=>'required',
        'company_name'=>'required',
        'location' =>'required',
        'start_date' => 'required|date|before:end_date',
        'end_date'=> Rule::excludeIf(fn () => request('currently_working')).'sometimes|date|after:start_date',
    ];
}
```

Even though I'm passing empty value to `end_date` with `currently_working` as false, I'm getting error

> 0: "The end date is not a valid date."

> 1: "The end date must be a date after start date."

How can I fix this, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "required_if" validation and add "currently_working" in your request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'employeee_type'=>'required',
        'company_name'=>'required',
        'location' =>'required',
        'start_date' => 'required|date|before:end_date',
        'currently_working ' => 'required|boolean',
        'end_date'=> 'required_if:currently_working ,==,false"|date|after:start_date',
    ];
}
```

link to laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: This will check whether the `currently_working` input has the string value "false"

Answer (score 0):

`excludeIf()` does not exclude the value from validation, it only excludes the value from the resulting array of validated data. You can [read documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-exclude-if) for more details. In addition, you can't just append the output of the `Rule` functions to a string.

A checkbox is not included at all in a post if it isn't checked, so you can simply apply the rule [if it's present in the request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation). It's not documented for some reason, but in a `FormRequest` class, this is done using the `withValidator()` method:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'employeee_type' => 'required',
        'company_name' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'start_date' => ['required', 'date', 'before:end_date'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 */
public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
{
    $validator->sometimes(
        'end_date',
        ['date', 'after:start_date'],
        fn (Fluent $input) => is_null($input->get('currently_working'))
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To perform Laravel date validation based on whether a checkbox is selected or not, you can use custom validation rules

```
if ($this->checkboxValue) {
        // Add your date validation logic here
        // For example, to validate a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, you can use:
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value) !== false;
    }
```

Use the custom validation rule in your Controller
Now, in your Laravel Controller that handles the form submission, you can use the custom validation rule like this:

```
 $request->validate([
    // Other validation rules for other fields
    'selected_date' => ['nullable', new ConditionalDateValidation($request->input('is_date_required'))],
]);
```